# Configuring Enzyme 3.x Adapter

Tags: javascript, testing, enzyme

I am writing tests for a React app using Jest and Enzyme. Enzyme 3.x introduced Adapters to provide compatibility across different versions of React. [The installation documentation](http://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/installation/) gives examples how to set this up:

```
// setup file
import { configure } from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';

configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });
```

What is this "setup file" referred to in the comment? Is this a file which can be run before all tests? Where does this file go in a React project? Does it need a particular name?

Comment: Are you using Jest along with enzyme?

Comment: @konekoya Yes, I am

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't need a particular name, and yes, it's run before any tests are.

You hook it up in your `package.json`'s `jest` stanza.

This is an example from a project I'm working on.

```
  "jest": {
    // other stuff...
    "setupFiles": [
      "./js/jest-setup.js"
    ],
    // ....
   }
```

The actual `js/jest-setup.js` file looks like this (i.e. like your example).

```
import Enzyme from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';

Enzyme.configure({adapter: new Adapter()});
```

Answer (score 1):

Enzyme has a nifty guide on setup here: https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/blob/master/docs/guides/jest.md

Though the initial step doesn't say it is the `package.json`.

Posting the relevant sections (with some minor tweaks) here so we don't lose it:

### Configure with Jest

To run the setup file to configure Enzyme and the Adapter with Jest direct `setupTestFrameworkScriptFile` to literally the string `<rootDir>` and the path to your setup file.

**package.json:**

```
{
  "jest": {
    "setupTestFrameworkScriptFile": "<rootDir>src/setupTests.js"
  }
}
```

### Jest version 15 and up

Starting with version 15, Jest [no longer mocks modules by default](https://facebook.github.io/jest/blog/2016/09/01/jest-15.html). Because of this, you no longer have to add *any* special configuration for Jest to use it with enzyme.

Install Jest, and its Babel integrations, as recommended in the [Jest docs](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/getting-started.html). Install enzyme. Then, simply require/import React, enzyme functions, and your module at the top of a test file.

**setupTests.js:**

```
import React from 'react';
import { shallow, mount, render } from 'enzyme';

import Foo from '../Foo';
```

Comment: What is `Foo`? Is that a component: `class Foo extends Component`? Do I put  the `Enzyme.configure()` call in `setupTests.js`?

Answer (score 1):

**What is this "setup file" referred to in the comment?** :
It's a way of running something before your test starting (some config for instance)

If you create your React Project using `react-create-app` you need or `eject` your application or pass a command set up your file `setupTest.js` (The name does not matter), but you need to identify in your command line, like this:

#### package.json

```
"scripts": {
  "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom --setupFiles=./src/test-setup.js",
},
```

#### test-setup.js

```
import './shim';
import { configure } from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';

configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });
```

#### shim.js (this is a hack to avoid the warning)

```
global.requestAnimationFrame = (callback) => {
    setTimeout(callback, 0);
};
```

Comment: When you say "this is a hack to avoid the warning", what warning are you referring to?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice the error is: `window.requestAnimationFrame is not a function`

This one:  https://github.com/One-com/react-truncate/issues/60

Comment: I have seen that error before, but not in this current project. It seems like a separate issue from my current question.

Comment: Yeah, it's just a bonus, just a piece of my configuration... :)

Answer (score 0):

Jest & enzyme configuration : 
Add following code in **package.json**

```
"jest": {
    "testEnvironment": "jsdom",
    "moduleDirectories": [
      "src",
      "node_modules"
    ],
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "\\.(css|scss)$": "<rootDir>/__mocks__/styleMock.js",
      "\\.(jpg|gif|ttf|eot|svg)$": "<rootDir>/__mocks__/fileMock.js"
    },
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(js|jsx)$": "babel-jest",
      ".+\\.(css|styl|less|sass|scss)$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/jest-css-modules-transform"
    },
    "setupTestFrameworkScriptFile": "<rootDir>/setupTests.js",
    "setupFiles": [
      "<rootDir>setup.js"
    ],
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "css",
      "scss",
      "js",
      "json",
      "jsx"
    ],
    "testRegex": "\/test\/spec\/.*\\.js$",
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "/node_modules/(?!test-component).+\\.js$"
    ]
  }
```

---

For setup of Enzyme => setup.js

```
import { configure } from 'enzyme'
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16'

configure({ adapter: new Adapter() })
```

---

For setupTestFrameworkScriptFile : setupTests.js
    global.fetch = require('jest-fetch-mock')

```
const { JSDOM } = require('jsdom')
const jsdom = new JSDOM('<!doctype html><html><body></body></html>')
const { window } = jsdom

const exposedProperties = ['window', 'navigator', 'document']
const { document } = new JSDOM('').window
global.document = document
global.window = document.defaultView
global.HTMLElement = window.HTMLElement
global.HTMLAnchorElement = window.HTMLAnchorElement

Object.keys(document.defaultView).forEach(property => {
  if (typeof global[property] === 'undefined') {
    exposedProperties.push(property)
    global[property] = document.defaultView[property]
  }
})

global.navigator = {
  userAgent: 'node.js',
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was just having this same issue and the easiest solution was to simply create a file named exactly `setupTests.js`, in the `src/` directory with the contents:

```
import { configure } from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';

configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });
```

Jest automatically detects it and the error goes away.

Answer (score 0):

With enzyme 3 we need an adapter. Adapter allows us to specify exactly which version of react we are gonna test against. This allows core enzyme library to be smaller. It does not need to have all of the code for all of the various versions of react that supported. Instead you just specify which one you need by installing the adapter that keeps the core library light and keeps your entire code base more manageable.

this is how u configure it:

in tests directory create any .js file:

tests/setupTest.js

```
import Enzyme from "enzyme";
import Adapter from "enzyme-adapter-react-16";

Enzyme.configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });
```

in the root directory create jest.config.json file and put this

```
{
  "setupFiles": ["raf/polyfill", "<rootDir>/src/tests/setupTest.js"],
}
```

NOTE:  We also need to install a polyfill module. Polyfill is known as request animation frame. Since we do not have it in test environment, we need to install.

```
 npm i raf --save
```

finally in package.json :

```
"test": "jest --config=jest.config.json"
```

Comment: Thank you for the information about why we use an Adapter now. However, this doesn't answer my original question about where to put the code from the documentation.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice sorry i missed that part. i updated the question

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Does this add any information that isn't already in the other answers?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I believe I am the only one who answered your all questions.